# Android Checkbox - control over an EditText?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext

I'd like a Checkbox to turn on or off notifications.  (I am not using this in a settings menu).

I simply would like an EditText field with a label and it to be slightly grayed out and non-clickable unless this checkbox is checked.  Once that happens, the EditText field comes to life and can be used.  How would one go about doing this?

Comment: And to gray out the EditText properly, you can simply call `myEditText.setEnabled(boolean)`. In the OnCheckedChangedListener, just do something like `myEditText.setEnabled(isChecked)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the checkbox oncheckchanged listener and modify the edittext when it's unchecked, more here: http://mgmblog.com/2008/02/18/android-checkbox-oncheckedchangelistener/